# How to redirect output from commands to a file in bash?

Tags: bash

I was wondering how to redirect the output from my bash file (which is getting its input from another redirect) to a txt file.

This is how I run my program:

```
$ ./myFile.bash < input.txt
```

I would like to save my output to some txt file (something like this):

```
$  out.txt < ( myFile.bash < input.txt )
```

What would be the most correct/formal/generic ways to go about this? Are there multiple options if any?

Comment: You might want to look into the syntax of `>`, `>>` and `|`. Those should be explained in any basic tutorial such as https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/bash/

But in short, `>` takes the output of a command and write it into a file. But be careful, that overrides the current of the file. `>>` appends the output to a file.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ./myFile.bash < input.txt > out.txt
```